# Ros Installation Win10 | rosout.exe not in directory

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosout, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

i installed ROS Melodic on Win10. Now when i run "roscore" the following error is displayed to me:

```
←[31mERROR: cannot launch node of type [rosout/rosout]: Cannot locate node of type [rosout] in package [rosout]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)←[0m←[31mRLException: failed to start core service [/rosout]←[0m←[31mThe traceback for the exception was written to the log file←[0m[master] killing on exit
```

I look in the path C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\lib\rosout, but this folder is empty (Actually there should be a rosout.exe in there).
Could it be that something went wrong with my installation or you can somehow post-install this rosout.exe into this folder.

I am glad about answers

Nils

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383998/ros-installation-win10-%7C-rosout.exe-not-in-directory/) by [Nils19024](https://answers.ros.org/users/80305/nils19024/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple things to try:

Do an update first:

```
set ChocolateyInstall=c:\opt\chocolatey
choco upgrade all -y --execution-timeout=0
```

Then try,

`choco upgrade ros-melodic-desktop_full -y` if there is an error message, then try the following:

```
choco uninstall ros-melodic-desktop_full
choco config set cacheLocation c:\new_temp
choco install ros-melodic-desktop_full
```

If still fails, I'd try re-installing using the following instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0